# How to Retrieve Data Using "OR" Operator

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

Let's say if I want to find if the people in a certain district (districtID=5) has taken Course A (cID=11 or cID=12) BUT **not** both since they have the **same course name** with different cID, how do you write this in SQL, along with their FirstName, LastName and Email?  Can you kindly help?  Here are the fields:

peopleID   FirstName   LastName   Email                     schoolIDNum
1               Esther         B                b@hotmail.com      33
2               Tommy        L                 l@hotmail.com       55

registrationID1   peopleIDNum   sectionIDNum
22                      1                      40
23                      2                      40

sectionID   courseIDNum   districtIDNum
40              11                    5
41              12                    5

schoolID   districtIDNum
33            5
55            5

My codes below didn't work. It keeps giving me **0** rows.

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, p.Email, s.CourseIDNum
  FROM People p, Registration r, Section s, School sc
 WHERE p.PeopleID=r.PeopleIDNum AND r.SectionIDNum=s.SectionID AND
       (s.CourseIDNum=11 OR s.CourseIDNum=12) AND sc.SchoolID=p.SchoolIDNum AND
       s.DistrictIDNum=5 AND r.Completed='Y'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try and avoid old style joins if I can, that way the where clause only contains actual clauses, and not a mix of joins and clauses.

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, p.Email, s.CourseIDNum
FROM People p
INNER JOIN Registration r
 on p.PeopleID = r.PeopleIdNum
INNER JOIN Section s
 on r.SectionIDNum = s.SectionID
INNER JOIN School sc
 on p.SchoolIDNum = sc.SchoolID
WHERE (s.CourseIDNum=11 AND s.CourseIDNum!=12)
  OR (s.CourseIDNum!=11 AND s.CourseIDNum=12)
```

But if you look at the data, the join cannot have both courses because the SecionID will always be 40 for these 2 people

Comment: Thank you!  It works.  Please advise what the exclamation mark (!) is as I haven't seen this before.

Comment: ah ok - i'm glad you got the answer - please up vote ;) - != mean "not equal"